# Change Platform toolset in many projects on the same solution C++ express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a solution that has more than 200 projects in C++ express. I'm asking if there is anyway to change the platform toolset of those 200 projects instead of changing it manually one by one. If anyone could please advise.

Comment: Why on _earth_ would you have 200 projects in a single solution?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did it by using shift on the keyboard to select all the existing projects.

Comment: that's right, otherwise just grep for *.vcxproj and change `<PlatformToolset>whatever</PlatformToolset>`

Answer (score 0):

Right-click solution -> Retarget solution